# How to use Geoloqi with Rubymotion?

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I am developing an iOS app using Rubymotion.
I want to integrate Geoloqi and I have added it to the vendor folder
and in the rakefile but when I build I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libGeoloqi-Debug.a(LQSession.o)
      objc-class-ref in libGeoloqi-Release.a(LQSession.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

What does it mean? Is there a gem or something to integerate Geoloqi with
a Rubymotion app?

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's docs MFMailComposeViewController is part of the MessageUI framework.

Try to add it in your Rakefile:

```
app.frameworks += %w[ MessageUI ]
```